# How to run a LIKE %..% query using RedBean

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

I would like to run a query at Redbean. 
The query is the following one

> "SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE name LIKE "%querystring%" OR
>   description LIKE  "%querystring%"

I tried the following one

```
$querystring = "querystring";
```

> R::findOne( 'SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE name LIKE ? OR description
>   LIKE ?', "%$querystring%");

However, this did not work, resulting in error 'Identifier does not conform to RedBeanPHP security policies'.

Another thing I tried was based on this:

> R::getAll( 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE title LIKE %:title%', 
>      [':title' => 'home']
>   );

That gave a RedBean error 'undefined offset: 0'

I'm trying to find a way to do this using prepared statements, so I don't want to construct the query as a string and send it to the server later.

Answer (score 4):

The syntax you need is following:

```
$mySearchString = "es";
$bean = R::find('bean',' name LIKE :name ',
  array(':name' => '%' . $mySearchString . '%' )
);
```

So as you see the LIKE is written without the wildcards in the sql statement, because that is part of the searchValue. Your first try was quite there, yet the problem was that you've written the php variable inside the quotes thus it didn't resolve.
Also findOne/find are the ORM features of RedBean which are not working with pure SQL strings. Take a closer look on the docs. If you need pure sql try R:getAll like you did. Same example with that one here

```
$mySearchString = "es";
$bean = R::getAll('SELECT * FROM bean WHERE name LIKE :name ',
  array(':name' => '%'.$mySearchString.'%' )
);

foreach($bean as $entry) {
    echo $entry['name'] . "<br />";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try that

```
   SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE name LIKE '%$querystring%' 
                       OR description LIKE '%$querystring%'
```

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use like:

```
"%".$querystring."%"
```

Comment: It says Identifier does not conform to RedBeanPHP security policies.